# Difference of the default order of primary keys between MySQL and MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My test server version is as following:

```
MySQL Server 5.7.20

MariaDB Server 10.1.9
```

And I made the same tables in two databases.

```
CREATE TABLE `sort_test` (
  `ind` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ind`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I inserted nine records in two tables

```
insert sort_test(time) values(now());
insert sort_test(time) values(now());
insert sort_test(time) values(now());
...
insert sort_test(time) values(now());
```

When I executed `SELECT * FROM sort_test order by time desc;`, the results was equals each other.

```
+-----+---------------------+
| ind | time                |
+-----+---------------------+
|   9 | 2018-01-05 23:43:59 |
|   8 | 2018-01-05 23:43:58 |
|   7 | 2018-01-05 23:43:57 |
|   6 | 2018-01-05 23:43:56 |
|   5 | 2018-01-05 23:43:55 |
|   4 | 2018-01-05 23:43:54 |
|   3 | 2018-01-05 23:43:53 |
|   2 | 2018-01-05 23:43:52 |
|   1 | 2018-01-05 23:43:51 |
+-----+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

By the way, when I executed `select * from (SELECT * FROM sort_test order by time desc) as A;`, the result was different.

```
mariadb> select * from (SELECT * FROM sort_test order by time desc) as A;
+-----+---------------------+
| ind | time                |
+-----+---------------------+
|   1 | 2018-01-05 23:43:51 |
|   2 | 2018-01-05 23:43:52 |
|   3 | 2018-01-05 23:43:53 |
|   4 | 2018-01-05 23:43:54 |
|   5 | 2018-01-05 23:43:55 |
|   6 | 2018-01-05 23:43:56 |
|   7 | 2018-01-05 23:43:57 |
|   8 | 2018-01-05 23:43:58 |
|   9 | 2018-01-05 23:43:59 |
+-----+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

versus

```
mysql> select * from (SELECT * FROM `sort_test` order by time desc) as A;
+-----+---------------------+
| ind | time                |
+-----+---------------------+
|   9 | 2018-01-05 23:43:59 |
|   8 | 2018-01-05 23:43:58 |
|   7 | 2018-01-05 23:43:57 |
|   6 | 2018-01-05 23:43:56 |
|   5 | 2018-01-05 23:43:55 |
|   4 | 2018-01-05 23:43:54 |
|   3 | 2018-01-05 23:43:53 |
|   2 | 2018-01-05 23:43:52 |
|   1 | 2018-01-05 23:43:51 |
+-----+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.10 sec)`
```

Results are sorted in **different order**.

Why? What happened?

Comment: Different optimizers may lead to a different access order, etc. The behavior of an order by is only defined if it is on the top-level query. Having an order by in  the table expression could for example be eliminated by the optimizer. The SQL spec says: _"If QE does not immediately contain an <order by clause>, then the ordering of rows in T is implementation-dependent."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know about it, but why is it different? How can I make the two results the same?

Comment: They are different because these are different database systems. They may have the same origin, but the implementation has diverged. I'd guess that even MySQL itself might behave differently when using different storage engines. How to fix this: the only guaranteed is way is to move the order by to the top-level query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Because of this problem, the same code shows different results on the test server and the real server.

Comment: The real problem is that your expectation is 'wrong', so you should either change the way you check the result (eg, use the same DBMS for both test and real server, don't take order into account, or something else), or fix the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Without an `ORDER BY`, you are not guaranteed an order of the results.*  You have no `ORDER BY` on the outer `SELECT`.  A subquery delivers an *unordered set* or rows.  That is, the Optimizer is free to ignore the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Whether the Optimizer takes this liberty depends on which version of which fork of MySQL you are looking at.  And maybe it also depends on the phase of the moon.

How can you make the results the same?  Well, why?  `SELECT * FROM ( subquery );` is unnecessary -- simply run the subquery.  OK, maybe you are doing something else that you simplified out of the query??  If so, put it back in so we can discuss *that*.

I was burned by this several years ago when the "groupwise max" code failed to work on some versions.

OK, there is a kludge that may do what you want for the near future:  Add a `LIMIT` with a large number to the subquery.  *Kludge!*

I'm with Mark -- your expectations are wrong.